# How many brothers does Vasudeva have?

Tags: mahabharata

And also what are their names? I only know 2 by the name Devashrava and Devabhaga, but can't seem to find his other brother's name.

Answer (score 7):

As per [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » Canto 9: Liberation
CHAPTER TWENTY-FOUR](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/24/), Surasena (Vasudeva's father) had 10 sons and 5 daughters which mean Vasudeva had 9 brothers named Devabhāga, Devaśravā, Ānaka, Sṛñjaya, Śyāmaka, Kaṅka, Śamīka, Vatsaka and Vṛka:

> Text 27:
> The three sons of Hṛdika were Devamīḍha, Śatadhanu and Kṛtavarmā. The son of Devamīḍha was Śūra, whose wife was named Māriṣā.

> Texts 28-31:
> Through Māriṣā, King Śūra begot **Vasudeva, Devabhāga, Devaśravā, Ānaka, Sṛñjaya, Śyāmaka, Kaṅka, Śamīka, Vatsaka and Vṛka**. These **ten sons** were spotlessly pious personalities. When Vasudeva was born, the demigods from the heavenly kingdom sounded kettledrums. Therefore Vasudeva, who provided the proper place for the appearance of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, was also known as Ānakadundubhi. The **five daughters** of King Śūra, named **Pṛthā, Śrutadevā, Śrutakīrti, Śrutaśravā and Rājādhidevī**, were Vasudeva’s sisters. Śūra gave Pṛthā to his friend Kunti, who had no issue, and therefore another name of Pṛthā was Kuntī.

Answer (score 4):

Vasudeva had 10 brothers

> **Through Māriṣā, King Śūra begot VASUDEVA, Devabhāga, Devaśravā, Ānaka, Sṛñjaya, Śyāmaka, Kaṅka, Śamīka, Vatsaka and Vṛka. These ten sons were spotlessly pious personalities.** When Vasudeva was born, the demigods from the heavenly kingdom sounded kettledrums. Therefore Vasudeva, who provided the proper place for the appearance of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, was also known as Ānakadundubhi. The five daughters of King Śūra, named Pṛthā, Śrutadevā, Śrutakīrti, Śrutaśravā and Rājādhidevī, were Vasudeva’s sisters. Śūra gave Pṛthā to his friend Kunti, who had no issue, and therefore another name of Pṛthā was Kuntī.
> -ŚB 9.24.28-31